# python : selecting row where y==1 and column is 0 in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I'm new to python. This is my code:

```
np.random.seed(42)
x1=np.random.randn(5,4)
y1=np.random.randint(0,2,(5,1))
print(x1)
print(y1)
```

I want to select x1's column 1 and rows where y is 1 :

```
print(x1[y1==1, 1])
```

but I am getting error `too many indices for array`

Answer (score 2):

You need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to extract an array of integers to feed NumPy indexing:

```
x1[np.where(y1==1)[0], 1]
```

To understand how this work, note that `y1 == 1` returns the following Boolean array:

```
array([[ True],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
```

`numpy.where` extracts indices of the `True` elements in the first element of the tuple returned:

```
print(np.where(y1==1))
(array([0, 1, 3], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int64))
```